# In java, how to write logs to a specific file appender of log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

If a log4j properties have multiple file appenders, then in Java how can I make sure that logs are written in a specific file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,out 

log4j.appender.SUCCESS_FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.SUCCESS_FILE.File=${dd.log.dir}/success.log

log4j.appender.VALID_FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.VALID_FILE.File=${dd.log.dir}/valid_error.log

log4j.appender.TEMP_FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.TEMP_FILE.File=${dd.log.dir}/Temp_error.tmp_log
```

In Java class, what can I do to write some messages to, lets say, SUCCESS_FILE and some messages to TEMP_FILE

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);
log.debug("This message should go to SUCCESS_FILE");
log.debug("This message should go to TEMP_FILE");
```

Comment: You need to filter the data. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/13408057/4807777

Comment: And note that some earlier versions may not support filters in property files configuration (but xml ones).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might help:-

```
log4j.appender.successLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.successLog.File=${dd.log.dir}/success.log

log4j.appender.tempLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.tempLog.File=${dd.log.dir}/Temp_error.tmp_log

log4j.category.successLogger=INFO, successLog
log4j.additivity.successLogger=false

log4j.category.tempLogger=INFO, tempLog
log4j.additivity.tempLogger=false
```

Access them like:-

```
static final Logger successLog = Logger.getLogger("successLogger");
static final Logger tempLog = Logger.getLogger("tempLogger");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I just found that instead of 'log4j.category.xx' and 'log4j.additivity.xx', we can just use 'log4j.logger.xx=INFO,fileAppenderName' and access the logger using the same way that you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Using XML configuration like @Nio answered is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="successLog" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="${dd.log.dir}/success.log" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="tempLog" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="${dd.log.dir}/Temp_error.tmp_log" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="successLogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="successLog"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="tempLogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="tempLog"/>
    </logger> 

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to write to 2 log files based on 2 appenders. This also write to console.

The log4j.properties file and java code is available [Here](https://www.developer-tricks.com/2020/01/log4j-how-to-write-log-to-multiple-log.html)

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ALL,STDOUT,debugLog
log4j.logger.reportsLogger=INFO,reportsLog
log4j.additivity.reportsLogger=false

log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C:%L - %m%n


# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.debugLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.debugLog.File="/Users/test/debuglog.log"
log4j.appender.debugLog.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.debugLog.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.debugLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.debugLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.reportsLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.reportsLog.File="/Users/test/reportslog.log"
log4j.appender.reportsLog.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.reportsLog.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.reportsLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.reportsLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C:%L - %m%n
```